# Fibonacci numbers expressed as squares of lower Fibonacci numbers

Tags: fibonacci-numbers, sums-of-squares

I am no mathematician so my apologies for my ignorance.

I notice that every number in the Fibonacci series can be expressed as a previous Fibonacci number squared plus or minus (alternating) another previous Fibonacci number squared, and both columns of squares themselves are composed of the Fibonacci sequence, each number appearing twice from 2 onwards. ie

```
1   1   +   0   1+0
1   1   -   0   1-0
2   1   +   1   1+1
3   2   -   1   4-1
5   2   +   1   4+1
8   3   -   1   9-1
13  3   +   2   9+4
21  5   -   2   25-4
34  5   +   3   25+9
55  8   -   3   64-9
89  8   +   5   64+25
144 13  -   5   169-25
233 13  +   8   169+64
377 21  -   8   441-64
610 21  +   13  441+169
987 34  -   13  1156-169
```

and so on.

Is this well known? Is there a proof that it works for all Fibonacci numbers?

Comment: This is not a research level question. There are infinitely many identities with Fibonacci numbers. If this one is true, it should be easily provable using the "$n$-th term formula".

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number

Answer (score 7):

It a derivation from the [Catalan and Cassini identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassini_and_Catalan_identities). Cassini identity states that:

$$F_n^2 - F_{n-r} \cdot F_{n+r} = (-1)^{n-r}F_r^2$$

Now set $r=n-1$ and we got:

$$F_n^2 - (-1)^{n-n+1}F_{n-1}^2 = F_{n - n+1}F_{n+n-1}$$
$$F_n^2 + F_{n-1}^2 = F_{2n - 1}$$

But $2n - 1$ is odd, so this covers the case when the Fibonacci index is odd number. Now by setting $r=n-2$ we have:

$$F_n^2 - (-1)^{n-n+2}F_{n-2}^2 = F_{n - n+2}F_{n+n-2}$$
$$F_n^2 - F_{n-2}^2 = F_{2n - 2}$$

This one covers the case when the Fibonacci index is even.